# Alpine.js and how to render row numbers on a table with nested x-for

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I am stuck trying to assign row number for a table.
The rendered "rowNumber" on each row have wrong values: 9, 8, 7, 5 and 6. The correct values from top to bottom are: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

this is the example code: https://jsfiddle.net/erxwjmts/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Alpine.js v3.x Ejemplo</title>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body class="p-m" x-data="componentData">


    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover m-t-md">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Number </th>
          <th> Sample Field </th>
          <th> Indexes </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <template x-for="(group1, index1) in arrayGroup1" :key="index1">
          <template x-for="(group2, index2) in group1.arrayGroup2" :key="index2">
            <template x-for="(group3, index3) in group2.arrayGroup3" :key="index3">
              <template x-for="(group4, index4 ) in group3.arrayGroup4" :key="index4">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    row number:
                    <span x-text="rowNumber++"></span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span x-text="group4.location"></span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div x-text="'index1:' + index1"></div>
                    <div x-text="'index2:' + index2"></div>
                    <div x-text="'index3:' + index3"></div>
                    <div x-text="'index4:' + index4"></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </template>
          </template>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  </body>

</html>
```

and the js script

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('componentData', () => ({
    "rowNumber": 0,
    "arrayGroup1": [{
        "id": 684,
        "formalName": "TRADING COMPANY NORTHERN ROSES LLC",
        "arrayGroup2": [{
            "nickName": "no-nickName",
            "arrayGroup3": [{
              "sid": "cid_11527",
              "type": "TypeOne",
              "id": 11527,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                  "location": "ESSAY LIVE, JOHN DOE, PLACE: SUGAR LOAF",
                  "samples": [{
                      "date": "2023-06-23",
                      "id": 66357
                    },
                    {
                      "date": "2023-06-23",
                      "id": 66356
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "location": "ESTATE FUTACUIN ROUTE 215 KM 60- PUYEHUE",
                  "samples": [{
                    "date": "2023-06-23",
                    "id": 66354
                  }]
                }
              ]
            }]
          },
          {
            "nickName": "John What",
            "arrayGroup3": [{
              "sid": "cid_11339",
              "type": "TypeOne",
              "id": 11339,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                "location": "SOME LOCATION BETWEEN STATES",
                "samples": [{
                  "date": "2023-06-23",
                  "id": 66355
                }]
              }]
            }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4556,
        "formalName": "JOHN DOE SMITH JOHNSON",
        "arrayGroup2": [{
          "nickName": "no-nickName",
          "arrayGroup3": [{
              "sid": "pid_1707",
              "type": "TypeTwo",
              "id": 1707,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                "location": "THE APPLE ORCHARD, SAINT CHARLES",
                "samples": [{
                  "date": "2023-06-23",
                  "id": 66347
                }]
              }]
            },
            {
              "sid": "cid_11577",
              "type": "TypeOne",
              "id": 11577,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                "location": "ROSE FLOWER, SAINT DOMINGO VALLEY",
                "samples": [{
                  "date": "2023-06-22",
                  "id": 66346
                }]
              }]
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }));
});
</script>
```

I get this advice from github: "Just put elements between the layers that have display: content Or fix your data." But sorry I don't understood that or how to fix it.

for now I use CSS counters, but it is not the ideal.

thanks

Comment: "The rendered "rowNumber" on each row have wrong values." – what would be the right values?

Comment: @Wongjn the wrong values: 9, 8, 7, 5 and 6. The correct values from top to bottom are: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. (question updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider flattening the `arrayGroup1` before passing to `x-for`:

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('componentData', () => ({
    "arrayGroup1": [{
        "id": 684,
        "formalName": "TRADING COMPANY NORTHERN ROSES LLC",
        "arrayGroup2": [{
            "nickName": "no-nickName",
            "arrayGroup3": [{
              "sid": "cid_11527",
              "type": "TypeOne",
              "id": 11527,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                  "location": "ESSAY LIVE, JOHN DOE, PLACE: SUGAR LOAF",
                  "samples": [{
                      "date": "2023-06-23",
                      "id": 66357
                    },
                    {
                      "date": "2023-06-23",
                      "id": 66356
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "location": "ESTATE FUTACUIN ROUTE 215 KM 60- PUYEHUE",
                  "samples": [{
                    "date": "2023-06-23",
                    "id": 66354
                  }]
                }
              ]
            }]
          },
          {
            "nickName": "John What",
            "arrayGroup3": [{
              "sid": "cid_11339",
              "type": "TypeOne",
              "id": 11339,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                "location": "SOME LOCATION BETWEEN STATES",
                "samples": [{
                  "date": "2023-06-23",
                  "id": 66355
                }]
              }]
            }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4556,
        "formalName": "JOHN DOE SMITH JOHNSON",
        "arrayGroup2": [{
          "nickName": "no-nickName",
          "arrayGroup3": [{
              "sid": "pid_1707",
              "type": "TypeTwo",
              "id": 1707,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                "location": "THE APPLE ORCHARD, SAINT CHARLES",
                "samples": [{
                  "date": "2023-06-23",
                  "id": 66347
                }]
              }]
            },
            {
              "sid": "cid_11577",
              "type": "TypeOne",
              "id": 11577,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                "location": "ROSE FLOWER, SAINT DOMINGO VALLEY",
                "samples": [{
                  "date": "2023-06-22",
                  "id": 66346
                }]
              }]
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    ],
    get renderGroups() {
      return this.arrayGroup1.flatMap(
        (group, index1) => group.arrayGroup2.flatMap(
          (group, index2) => group.arrayGroup3.flatMap(
            (group, index3) => group.arrayGroup4.flatMap(
              (group, index4) => ({
                ...group,
                index1,
                index2,
                index3,
                index4
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Alpine.js v3.x Ejemplo</title>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body class="p-m" x-data="componentData">


    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover m-t-md">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Number </th>
          <th> Sample Field </th>
          <th> Indexes </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <template x-for="(group, rowNumber) in renderGroups" :key="rowNumber">
          <tr>
            <td>
              row number:
              <span x-text="rowNumber + 1"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span x-text="group.location"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div x-text="'index1:' + group.index1"></div>
              <div x-text="'index2:' + group.index2"></div>
              <div x-text="'index3:' + group.index3"></div>
              <div x-text="'index4:' + group.index4"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  </body>

</html>
```

Though this gives a different order to the elements due the nature of how Alpine expands the nested `<template>` elements:

[image]

If you need to preserve the same order, you could consider waiting until all the rows are rendered via `$nextTick()` and then using element `$refs` to find where the rows are in relation to the `<tbody>` parent:

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('componentData', () => ({
    "arrayGroup1": [{
        "id": 684,
        "formalName": "TRADING COMPANY NORTHERN ROSES LLC",
        "arrayGroup2": [{
            "nickName": "no-nickName",
            "arrayGroup3": [{
              "sid": "cid_11527",
              "type": "TypeOne",
              "id": 11527,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                  "location": "ESSAY LIVE, JOHN DOE, PLACE: SUGAR LOAF",
                  "samples": [{
                      "date": "2023-06-23",
                      "id": 66357
                    },
                    {
                      "date": "2023-06-23",
                      "id": 66356
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "location": "ESTATE FUTACUIN ROUTE 215 KM 60- PUYEHUE",
                  "samples": [{
                    "date": "2023-06-23",
                    "id": 66354
                  }]
                }
              ]
            }]
          },
          {
            "nickName": "John What",
            "arrayGroup3": [{
              "sid": "cid_11339",
              "type": "TypeOne",
              "id": 11339,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                "location": "SOME LOCATION BETWEEN STATES",
                "samples": [{
                  "date": "2023-06-23",
                  "id": 66355
                }]
              }]
            }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4556,
        "formalName": "JOHN DOE SMITH JOHNSON",
        "arrayGroup2": [{
          "nickName": "no-nickName",
          "arrayGroup3": [{
              "sid": "pid_1707",
              "type": "TypeTwo",
              "id": 1707,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                "location": "THE APPLE ORCHARD, SAINT CHARLES",
                "samples": [{
                  "date": "2023-06-23",
                  "id": 66347
                }]
              }]
            },
            {
              "sid": "cid_11577",
              "type": "TypeOne",
              "id": 11577,
              "arrayGroup4": [{
                "location": "ROSE FLOWER, SAINT DOMINGO VALLEY",
                "samples": [{
                  "date": "2023-06-22",
                  "id": 66346
                }]
              }]
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Alpine.js v3.x Ejemplo</title>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body class="p-m" x-data="componentData">


    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover m-t-md">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Number </th>
          <th> Sample Field </th>
          <th> Indexes </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody x-ref="tbody">
        <template x-for="(group1, index1) in arrayGroup1" :key="index1">
          <template x-for="(group2, index2) in group1.arrayGroup2" :key="index2">
            <template x-for="(group3, index3) in group2.arrayGroup3" :key="index3">
              <template x-for="(group4, index4 ) in group3.arrayGroup4" :key="index4">
                <tr x-data="{rowNumber:''}" x-init="$nextTick(() => { rowNumber = Array.from($refs.tbody.children).filter(({ tagName }) => tagName ===  'TR').indexOf($root) + 1})">
                  <td>
                    row number:
                    <span x-text="rowNumber"></span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span x-text="group4.location"></span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div x-text="'index1:' + index1"></div>
                    <div x-text="'index2:' + index2"></div>
                    <div x-text="'index3:' + index3"></div>
                    <div x-text="'index4:' + index4"></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </template>
          </template>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  </body>

</html>
```